# Insert multiple rows into table sql, oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have used the following code to insert into my table but when executed, it says 0 rows effected.

```
insert ALL 
INTO CUSTOMER (CustomerID, FirstName, Surname, Address, ContactNumber, Email) 
VALUES
('11011', 'Jeffery', 'Smith', '18 Water Rd', '0877277521', 'jef@isat.com')
INTO CUSTOMER (CustomerID, FirstName, Surname, Address, ContactNumber, Email) 
VALUES
('11012', 'Alex', 'Hendricks', '22 Water Rd', '0863257857', 'ah@mcom.co.za')
INTO CUSTOMER (CustomerID, FirstName, Surname, Address, ContactNumber, Email) 
VALUES
('11013', 'Johnson', 'Clark', '101 Summer Lane', '0834567891', 'jclark@mcom.co.za')
INTO CUSTOMER (CustomerID, FirstName, Surname, Address, ContactNumber, Email) 
VALUES
('11014', 'Henry', 'Jones', '55 Mountain Way', '0612547895', 'hj@isat.co.za')
INTO CUSTOMER (CustomerID, FirstName, Surname, Address, ContactNumber, Email) 
VALUES
('11015', 'Andre', 'Williams', '5 Main Rd', '0827238521', 'aw@mcal.co.za')
select * from CUSTOMER;
```

Comment: Please format your code using code icon which separate the code from normal text. In the values clause please put the name of the column.

Comment: Also, since you are inserting your own value rather than value from existing table you can use select * from dual at the end.

Comment: Presumably your customer table started off empty. It would need exactly one existing row to work though; more would create duplicates. Make it `select * from dual` instead.